# Foreach if value is get other value of array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Here is my array so far.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => first
            [value] => First
            [active] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key] => second
            [value] => Second
            [active] => 1
        )

)
```

Now i want to check whit php if active is 1 and than get the value out of this array whit active is 1 and echo it.
But I'm not sure how can i get there with a foreach.

I try this:

```
$found = false;
    foreach ($this->array as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == 1) {
             $found = true;
        }
    }
```

But then I'm not sure hot to loop again and get value.

Comment: Well have you started and tried something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP 5.5 and newer

```
$key = array_search(1, array_column($your_array, 'active'));

echo $your_array[$key]['value'];
```

Comment: You just completely posted the exact same answer from an hour ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31658554/3933332 And you even messed it up.

Comment: *//EUR* You get this as output with the array from OP given here? I don't see that anywhere in OP's code, I wonder from where you got this output... ?!